# Babel JS - setup project

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I want to use ECMAScript, as I understand Babel can compile my ES script to JavaScript.

So I have my project/app - few folders with ES files. How can I setup Babel configuration for input files & output files?

Can I give babel list of input files and then get one output file?
Maybe Babel is not the tool that I looking for?

Comment: JavaScript is an instantiation of the ECMAScript standard. You can't compile/transpile one into the other. There are different JavaScript versions that implement different standards such as ECMAScript 5. Which standard version do you have problems with?

Comment: I am frontend web developer, so I wanted to write all angularJS things ( Controllers \ Services ) in ECMAScript ( much easy to create classes ). But browsers are not support ECMAScript, so I need to transform it to simple javascript code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is a bundler, such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673077/including-all-scripts-in-separate-file/32673135#32673135) for more details.

Babel is a tool for compiling ES6 javascript back into ES5 so that you can take advantage of all of its modern features now, such as classes, destructuring, generators, etc.

Comment: Hmm.. I liked requirejs, but I still have problem with ES files.. I have to support IE8, I need to convert that ES files to old JS code. What can I do?

Comment: I haven't personally used that combination of tools, but it looks like babel/requirejs integration is supported. See: [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#requirejs) and [this](https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel).

Answer (score 0):

I think ES6 and ES7 are useful for our development, you should learn them and use them in your project which can give you a more convenient and rapid development process.

You can just learn it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).